# appendChild does not work on shop website

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

i was making a website with a function to add products on the homepage. The user entered the name, price and description of the product. but when publishing this product on the homepage, he does not appear. All the code works, except for appendChild()

first html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Loja</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f2a567fbc9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"defer ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Loja TemDeTudo</h1>

        <ul class="list">
            <a href="criar.html"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i></li></a>
            <!--<i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>-->
        </ul>
    </header>

    <main class="posts">
        <ul class="produtos">

        
        </ul>
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

second html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Loja</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f2a567fbc9.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Loja TemDeTudo</h1>

        <ul class="list">
            
            <a href="index.html"><li><i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i></li></a>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <main class="criaposts">
        <input id="nome" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="nome do produto"><br>
        <input id="price" type="number" name="" id="" placeholder="preço em R$"><br>
        <textarea name="" id="descrição" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="descrição do produto"></textarea><br>
        <a href="index.html"><button class="cancel">cancelar</button></a>
        <a href="index.html" id="ancora"><button class="confirm" id="add">confirmar</button></a>
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

css file:

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: purple;
    color: whitesmoke;
}

.list {
    margin-left: 60%;
    font-size: 40px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 177);
    transition-duration: .6s;
    cursor: pointer;
   
}



.list:hover {
    color:purple;
    background-color:  rgb(255, 255, 177);
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
}

textarea {
    resize: none;
    margin-top: 1.3rem;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 1rem;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border-color: black;
}

.criaposts {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
}

input {
    font-size: 22px;
    border: none;
    margin-top: 1.1em;
    width: 25%;
    outline: none;
    padding: .3em;
    
}


textarea:focus {
    border-color: black;
}

button {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 1rem;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: whitesmoke;
    transition-duration: .3s;
}

.confirm {
    background-color: rgb(9, 255, 0);
}

.cancel {
    background-color: crimson;
}

.cancel:hover , .confirm:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}

.posts {
    margin-top: 3em;
    margin-left: 8rem;
}

.produtos {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.detalhes {
    margin-top: 5em;
}

p {
    margin-top: 1em;
    color: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    opacity: .95;
}

.produtosPub {
    transition-duration: .2s;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: 15%;
}

.produtosPub:hover {
    opacity: .8;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
```

js file:

```
const add = document.querySelector("#add");
const posts = document.querySelector(".posts");
const ancora = document.querySelector("#ancora");
const produtos = document.querySelector(".produtos")


add.addEventListener("click" , () => {
   
    const nomeProdu = document.querySelector("#nome").value;
    const price = document.querySelector("#price").value;
    const descriçao = document.querySelector("#descrição").value;
    

    if(nomeProdu.length > 25) {
        alert("o nome está muito grande");
        ancora.removeAttribute("href");
        nomeProdu = "";
    }

    else if(!nomeProdu || !price || !descriçao) {
        ancora.removeAttribute("href");
        alert("Esta faltando informações do produto");
        
        nomeProdu = "";
        price = "";
        descriçao = "";
    }

    else {
        ancora.setAttribute("href","index.html");
        const lista = document.createElement("li");
        lista.classList.add("produtosPub");
        
        lista.innerHTML = `<h2>${nomeProdu}</h2>
        <div class="detalhes">
            <h2>
                R$: ${price}
            </h2>

            <p>
                ${descriçao}
            </p>
        </div>`
        
        produtos.appendChild(lista)
    }
})
```

i don't know why this is happening.

I've already tried changing the appendChild() to the innerHTML and it keep going wrong

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: JavaScript can only update the current DOM. You can't append to elements in a different web page. So you can't access `produtos` from the JavaScript running in the second HTML file.

Comment: Remember, you're just updating the DOM in the current page, not editing HTML files. If you want something to persist, you need to use a database on the server.

Comment: yes. there is  an error in the console  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')" . I just want to add, no need to remain. Thanks for answering

Comment: "JavaScript can only update the current DOM. You can't append to elements in a different web page. So you can't access produtos from the JavaScript running in the second HTML file."             thank you, I didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Based on your JS code, you don't wait for the page to load fully before running `querySelector` queries. This could lead to `produtos` equal to `undefined`.

Please check the browser's console for errors to check this theory.

Ideally, you should run any JS code after this event is triggered

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // your JS initialization code here
});
```

This will ensure that all the components on the page are created and ready to be accessed via `querySelector`.

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: i tried but it didn't work. a message appears on the console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')".